# Error when exporting nif

Tags: export

I'm trying to export as nif, but i get this error whenever I try.
[image]

When I apply size and rotation it looks like this
[image]
and still gives the same error.

Comment: I would consider any error pop-up taken directly from a python exception to be a bug.

Comment: the error says "non uniform scaling not supported. workaround: apply size and rotation (ctrl-A) on 'plane.002'", is the below image what you have after  trying that workaround? in that shape it is exportable without errors? you should investigate on why such a difference happens... maybe there's some weirdness, which the exporting addon is complaining about...